# how to use apply instead of a loop in R

Tags: r, apply, sapply, tapply, mapply

I am trying to write an algorithm which is very computationally intensive and hence I want to replace every loop with an apply function. However I am pretty stack in the following loop and I am wondering if anyone has any ideas. bc is a matrix of 0s and 1s and ac is a matrix of zeros with the same dim as bc.

```
for (i in 1:nr){                               
  for (j in 1:nr){
    ac[i,j] <- (bc[i,j]+bc[j,i])/2          
  }
}
```

Comment: NB The answer below is better, quicker, more concise as it is **vectorised**. The `apply` like functions are just syntactic sugar - simpler, clearer - but no more efficient or quicker than loops.

Answer (score 3):

We can get the sum of `bc` and transpose of `bc` and divide by 2.

```
(bc+t(bc))/2
```

Or

```
Reduce(`+`, list(bc, t(bc)))/2
```

#### data

```
bc <- matrix(1:25, 5,5)
nr <- 5
ac <- matrix(,5,5)
```

Comment: Not sure what the `Reduce` solution would bring to the table here … After all, nobody would ever write `a + b` as `Reduce('+', list(a, b))`. Yet this is the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  If there are many datasets, using `+` many times will be difficult, so I thought the `Reduce` as useful.

Comment: @Akis I came to know about these methods from the posts of geniuses in stackoverflow and R mailing list (including the ones who commented here).